# Probability of finding at most 1 defective dvd out of a sample of 50 when 1/200 is usually defective.

Tags: probability

experience has shown that 1/200 of all dvds produced by a certain machine are defective. if a quality control technician randomly test 50 dvds, find the prob that at most one is defective. n=50, p=.005, x=0,1 q=.995. when I run the numbers through for 0 and 1 I keep getting 0, as .005^50=0 which would make everything 0. lost on this one

Answer (score 1):

You were barking up the wrong tree !

For $x = 0, Pr = 0.995^{50}$

If you similarly compute correctly for x = 1, you should get the right answer,

Answer (score 1):

Again, you're modelling the count $X$, as having a Binomial Distribution, $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(50, 1/200)$, so:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x) & = \dbinom{50}{x}\dfrac{1^x 199^{50-x}}{200^{50}} \\[2ex] \mathsf P(X\leq 1) & = \dfrac{199^{50}+50\cdot 199^{49}}{200^{50}}
\\[1ex] & \approx 0.974 
\end{align}$$

**tl;dr** check your peas and queues